# How to get array of values with same condition

Tags: javascript, json

I have array which i got as a result from nodeJS code

Original JSON data:

JS code:

```
setInterval(function() {
  var notify = db.get('users')
    .filter({notify: "true"})
    .value()
    console.log("1");
    console.log(notify);

}, 10 * 1000);
```

Result:

```
[ { uid: '177098244407558145',
    pubgUser: 'Jengas',
    pubgServer: 'pc-eu',
    notify: 'true' },
  { uid: '407970368847085578',
    pubgUser: 'Lovec_Pokemonov',
    pubgServer: 'pc-eu',
    notify: 'true' },
  { uid: '4307970368847085578',
    pubgUser: 'Lossvec_Pokemonov',
    pubgServer: 'pc-eu',
    notify: 'true' },
  { uid: '407970368847015578',
    pubgUser: 'SDLovec_Pokemonov',
    pubgServer: 'pc-eu',
    notify: 'true' } ]
```

I wanted to get all `uid` values which had "true". But result was giving me "undefined" for `console.log(notify.uid);`

Expected result: `177098244407558145, 407970368847085578, 4307970368847085578, 407970368847015578`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method in combination with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

For this, you have to pass a **callback** function for each of the two methods or just use `arrow` functions which are specific for latest versions of `ES`.

```js
let data = [ { uid: '177098244407558145', pubgUser: 'Jengas', pubgServer: 'pc-eu', notify: 'true' }, { uid: '407970368847085578', pubgUser: 'Lovec_Pokemonov', pubgServer: 'pc-eu', notify: 'true' }, { uid: '4307970368847085578', pubgUser: 'Lossvec_Pokemonov', pubgServer: 'pc-eu', notify: 'true' }, { uid: '407970368847015578', pubgUser: 'SDLovec_Pokemonov', pubgServer: 'pc-eu', notify: 'true'}  ]
    
uid_array = data.filter(a => a.notify).map(a => a.uid);
console.log(uid_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

notify type is string so we need to check with 'true'

```js
let data = [ { uid: '177098244407558145', pubgUser: 'Jengas', pubgServer: 'pc-eu', notify: 'true' }, { uid: '407970368847085578', pubgUser: 'Lovec_Pokemonov', pubgServer: 'pc-eu', notify: 'true' }, { uid: '4307970368847085578', pubgUser: 'Lossvec_Pokemonov', pubgServer: 'pc-eu', notify: 'true' }, { uid: '407970368847015578', pubgUser: 'SDLovec_Pokemonov', pubgServer: 'pc-eu', notify: 'false'}  ]
    
uid_array = data.filter(a => a.notify==='true').map(a => a.uid);
console.log(uid_array);
```